# What happens to the Queens Speech now?

Tags: united-kingdom, prorogation

Boris Johnson prorogued Parliament from the 9th-12th of September to the 14th of October with the stated intention to have a Queens Speech on the 14th of October and the subsequent opening of a new session of Parliament.

This prorogation has now been ruled unlawful by the UK Supreme Court, and Parliament has been allowed back into session as if nothing happened (literally, the order to prorogue Parliament was considered "null and void, as if the order given was a blank piece of paper").

So what happens now with the intended Queens Speech on the 14th of October?  Does it go ahead, or has that also been vacated by the act of the prorogation being vacated?

Can Johnson prorogue Parliament again on the 7th of October to fall in line with it being a justifiable prorogation based on normal events leading up to a Queens Speech (where a prorogation normally lasts less than a calendar week)?

Comment: Assuming it goes ahead, it would be interesting to see if the Queen herself is going to deliver it, given how BoJo made her look with the (illegal) prorogation business...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Queen' Speech can only be given if Parliament has been prorogued. Given that there legally has not be a prorogation, there currently cannot be a Queens Speech.

By my understanding of the court ruling, there can be a prorogation in the future. The Supreme Court found that this prorogation was void because it frustrated the will of Parliament and prevented debate and scrutiny, due to timing and the length of the prorogation.

The courts did not rule out future prorogation, given that they cannot. This means that there could be a short prorogation in preparation for a Queens Speech. But until such a prorogation occurs there cannot be a Queens Speech as this session of parliament is still in session.

Comment: To be precise, a prorogation if the length suggested by Major as the general time to prepare a queen's speech would be hard to challenge if done now